# Android devie mic is take over when HDMI via USB is attached

Tags: android, usb, hdmi

I have simple voice recognition app that works well using onboard mic, but as soon as I attach a HDMI cable (via HDMI Capture card - USB-C) - the android device mic is taken over. How do I prevent that from happening?

For my app to work, I must connect the HDMI & still keep the voice recognition part running. These two things in isolation work, I can receive HDMI input & record video feed, I can use voice recognition - but when these two are combined - I lose the mic.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Android uses audio routing rules when peripherals are attached. I was able to work around this by changing settings as follows ...

> Go to Settings > System > Developer Options. Scroll down until you find the “Media” options. Tap on “Disable USB Audio Routing” and disable this option.

Comment: any further investigation on this? have you found any programmatic way?

Comment: No, I didn’t explore further (yes)

Comment: Is there any programmatic way to disable USB Audio Routing without enabling developer options?